# How to use MySQL REPLACE with variables?

Tags: mysql, replace

I understand that MySQL's `REPLACE` can be used with `INSERT` and `UPDATE` queries, but how do I use it replace strings within a declared variable ?

This is the code I'm trying, but it doesn't work:

```
DECLARE genre_string VARCHAR(255);

SET genre_string = 'drama, thriller';

SET genre_string = REPLACE(genre_string,'drama','Drama');

SELECT genre_string;
```

How I get it to work on currently declared variables too ?

Comment: Don't you have to add @ in front of your variable when you use it?

Comment: I get what you're trying to do, but I'm having a hard time understanding why. Sometimes the solution isn't to treat symptons, but instead fix the underlying problem. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I'm importing some data, and then cleaning out the strings a little, before inserting them elsewhere .. Data imported is coming from an Excel file, and yes I can clean it there, but since the import is done very often, it will be better to clean it in this SP as it will be quicker ..

Comment: @Ahmad I'm assuming you have some program that does the import. Make the string replacement there. Or doing `SELECT REPLACE('drama, thriller','drama','Drama');` will yield you the same result. More importantly, however, is that you shouldn't add multiple genres into one field, but instead normalize your data.

Comment: Don't worry about the last part, the Stored Procedure is later on spltting the string up and processing each genre separately .. Source data uses that structure and nothing can be done about that ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below works for me:

```
DECLARE @genre_string VARCHAR(255);

SET @genre_string = 'drama, thriller';

SET @genre_string = REPLACE(@genre_string,'drama','Drama');

SELECT @genre_string
```

Comment: `@` is for used-defined variables and shouldn't be declared. Your last three lines will work alone. You only need to declare local variables.

Comment: I forgot to use the `genre_string =` in front `REPLACE`, which was causing the problem :)